# Select a random value from a selection of random keys from a Python dictionary

Tags: python, function, dictionary, python-2.7

So as I stated before, I'm working on trying to make a multiple choice quiz. The quiz would grab 3 keys at random as the "answers". Then the quiz would take the value of the 3 selected keys and utilize it as a "question." I'm trying to utilize random.sample as an argument to select a value from randomly selected key values. My code is below:

```
import random

word_drills = {'class': 'Tell Python to make a new kind of thing.',
               'object': 'Two meanings: the most basic kind of thing, and any instance of some thing.',
               'instance': 'What you get when you tell Python to create a class.',
               'def': 'How you define a function inside a class.',
               'self': 'Inside the functions in a class, self is a variable for the instance/object being accessed.',
               'inheritance': 'The concept that one class can inherit traits from another class, much like you and your parents.',
               'composition': 'The concept that a class can be composed of other classes as parts, much like how a car has wheels.',
               'attribute': 'A property classes have that are from composition and are usually variables.',
               'is-a': 'A phrase to say that something inherits from another, as in a Salmon *** Fish',
               'has-a': 'A phrase to say that something is composed of other things or has a trait, as in a Salmon *** mouth.'}


def nodupchoice():
    key1, key2, key3 = random.sample(word_drills, 3)
    print "%s, %s, %s" % (key1, key2, key3)
    #print word_drills.random.sample[key1, key2, key3]
    #print word_drills[key1]
    #print word_drills[random.sample(key1, key2, key3)]


nodupchoice()
```

You will notice that I have commented out what I thought would actually give me the results I desired. Unfortunately, each one did not. Any assistance of guidance would be appreciated. Thanks again.

***UPDATE***

So I have incorporated the new information provided. Thank you again. This is what I came up with:

```
import random

word_drills = {'class': 'Tell Python to make a new kind of thing.',
               'object': 'Two meanings: the most basic kind of thing, and any instance of some thing.',
               'instance': 'What you get when you tell Python to create a class.',
               'def': 'How you define a function inside a class.',
               'self': 'Inside the functions in a class, self is a variable for the instance/object being accessed.',
               'inheritance': 'The concept that one class can inherit traits from another class, much like you and your parents.',
               'composition': 'The concept that a class can be composed of other classes as parts, much like how a car has wheels.',
               'attribute': 'A property classes have that are from composition and are usually variables.',
               'is-a': 'A phrase to say that something inherits from another, as in a Salmon *** Fish',
               'has-a': 'A phrase to say that something is composed of other things or has a trait, as in a Salmon *** mouth.'}


def nodupchoice():
    # For loop that creates a list named keys. It grabs 3 random keys from the dictionary word_drills
    keys = [x for x in random.sample(word_drills, 3)]
    # User is presented with a question. A value from the previous randomly selected keys is selected as the 'question'
    print "Question: ", word_drills[random.choice(keys)]
    # Set the variables key1, key2, & key3 to the 3 keys in the list 'keys'
    key1, key2, key3 = keys[0], keys[1], keys[2]
    # User is presented with 3 choices.
    print "\n\n(a)%s   (b)%s   (c)%s" % (key1, key2, key3)
    selection = raw_input("> ")
    print selection

nodupchoice()
```

The issue I'm trying to decipher now would be: How to check the users selection against what is in the dictionary word_drills. I was planning on using an if/else. If it was correct, it would notify you, else you were incorrect. Not sure how to approach this however. Just wanted to thank everyone again for the assistance, it is definitely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try using [random.choice()](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.choice) to select the key:

```
keys = random.sample(word_drills, 3)
print keys
print word_drills[random.choice(keys)]
```

Outputs:

```
['has-a', 'attribute', 'class']
A phrase to say that something is composed of other things or has a trait, as in a Salmon *** mouth.
```

Comment: I don't understand what role the listcomp is playing here.  Won't `lst` always be equal to `random.sample(word_drills, 3)`?

Comment: Yes, it will. It's just a short-hand in this case to make it easier to use random.choice() and print all the selected keys.

Comment: I guess what DMS meant is: `random.sample` already returns a list/iterable, so it doesn't have to be wrapped again.

Comment: Oh! I see. Yes, you're both right. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: I went ahead and added the changes to the post above. However, I'm faced with another issue as noted above.

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you wanted to do is this:

```
print word_drills[random.choice([key1, key2, key3])]
```

This will print one of the values that belong to one of the randomly sampled keys.

Comment: I want the program to randomly select one of the values from key1, key2, & key3. That way, I can guarantee when the value (or question) gets displayed, its corresponding key (or answer) has already appeared as a possible choice.

Comment: That'd work but I think there might be a closing parenthesis missing after `key3]`